# System Resource Exceeded when alter table counter (autonumber)

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I make a simple program in excel that connect to access. The user of this program not good with coding/access, So it should be done with only a few clicks.

the workflow:
1. Import the raw data from BW (in excel) to access. (without ID and has 28k rows)
2. Add the ID Column with autonumber

I use this code for the second part:

```
   acObj.CurrentDb.Execute "ALTER TABLE " & ptableName & " ADD COLUMN ID COUNTER (1, 1);", dbFailOnError
```

and appears error : 3035 system resource exceeded.

*with only 16k rows works just fine.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could remove `dbFailOnError`, and use `dbInconsistent` instead. That way the query is executed non-transactionally.

The odds of this query failing are pretty much none (it fails if there already is an ID column, but you can check for that). Executing it non-transactionally means Access doesn't have to cache the result, and it uses less system resources.